# Excel : Formula with cell updating

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel sheet ("month payslip") in which there is a payslip with a *lot* of formulas.

There is some value that changes each month like the **Nomber of hours** to make it simple.

The amount earned after charges is computed in this first sheet.

In another sheet ("year payslip"), I have a table with, for each month, the **number of hours** worked in the month. 

I would like excel to compute the net salary for each month, using the first sheet to compute it.

It would be easy with a VBA macro that does the following process :

1. Copy hours of month ***i***
2. Paste it on the sheet 1
3. Copy the computed Salary
4. Paste it on the sheet 2 just below month ***i***
5. Do it again for month ***i + 1***

**But I want to know if this simple process is possible *only with formulas* and without *VBA***

Comment: what version of excel are you using?

Comment: The version I use is Excel 2010

Comment: Hi friend, can you upload a sheet with dummy data and expected result?

Comment: I think you can't solve without VBA or refactoring. To calculate many time the monthly payslip you really need to replicate the many formulas in the sheet. Maybe if you could refactor the sheet streamlining the formulas in a single row then maybe you could more easily do it. Of course if you need help for the refactoring you need to post the sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably use `SUMIF` or `SUMIFS` depending on  your source data.

Please edit your question with the columns you have and how you would want them to be processed to get the Sheet 2.

Comment: I this this formula is the most approaching solution. Thank you. But There might not be perfect solution without VBA...

Answer (score 0):

in excel 2007/2010 you could use scenerio manager to do something similar. but for a good and satisfactory result you should use vba.
actually just recording a macro , without even further editing is **very** simple. just record starting from the first cell in the month table, copy the results back and forth and set the mouse a cell down.  then you could encapsulate the macro in a vb for loop: something like:
(get into the vba editing screen with f-11)

```
sub yearly()
var i
for i = 1 to 12
    \\put your macrocode here
next i
```

good luck

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I'm a good vba programer, its not the problem. I really wanted not to use VBA.

Comment: sorry, had the wrong impression from the not use vba question.